# Sharing Graphics between WPF and Winforms

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have a number of png, bitmaps and icons which I want to use in both Winforms projects and WPF projects.

I'm comfortable with using resources in winforms, and happy with resources in WPF.

What are people doing where they have common resources shared by both? My current feeling is to have a WPF resource assembly and a Winforms resource assembly, but none of the approaches I've looked at seem fluid.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a project with both WPF and Winforms controls. This project have resource folder, which contains all the images. Than I simply load them from the disk using relative path.
Assuming that your project name is "MyProject", and the images path is a folder named "MyImages", inside the projects folder, and your image name is "MyImage.bmp" you can load them as follows:

**In Winforms:**

```
new Bitmap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.MyImages.MyImage.bmp")
```

**In WPF**

```
 <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/MyProject;Component/MyImages/MyImage.bmp">
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Yes, I think it does. I might add a helper to both to automatically establish what resources are available, but your answer has put my mind at rest. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Amittai Shapira works if build action is set to "Embedded resource". If you set build action to "Resource", then you could use:

**WinForms:**

```
Bitmap photo;
var picUri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/MyImages/MyImage.bmp", UriKind.Absolute);
var resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(picUri);

if (resourceInfo != null)
{
   photo = new Bitmap(resourceInfo.Stream);
}
```

**WPF:**

```
<Image Source="MyImages/MyImage.bmp"/>
```